# CPLEX Binary Variable in Python

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, docplex

I am trying to set up a binary variable for my optimization problem in Python by using the IBM CPLEX. In my objective function, I set up a line which turns on and off depending on the market price in t:

```
mdl.maximize(
mdl.sum( (1-b[t]) * (prod_diff[t] * price_diff[t]) + \
(b[t]) * (vol_t * price[t] + prod_diff[t] * price_spot[t]) for t in time
)
```

Subject to:

```
mdl.add_constraint(
if prod_diff[t] <= 0:
b= 0
else:
b= 1
)
```

Apparently, there is something called logical and conditional constraints; but, unfortunately, I was unable to set it up in Python.

I'm new to this; can anyone put some light on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In [easy python optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)  see

[if then](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooifthen.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint
mdl.add(mdl.if_then(nbbus40>=3,nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

 

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I saw that example, but the problem is that i have a set of values for all those parameters in the objective function that are being either calcualted or pulled from an excel sheet over each iteration [t]. Is there any option to set up the if_then constrain differently?

Comment: Yes see https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoological.py

Comment: im getting the DOcplexException: Expecting linear constraint, got: True error